# How to delete from configuration file variable that not equal to 100

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, sed, perl

How to delete from configuration file the variable/s **hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize** that are not equal to 100

example

```
more file.conf

hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=107
hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=10
hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=100
hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=189
hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=104
hadoop.tasklog.purgeLogSplits=true
hadoop.tasklog.logsRetainHours=12
.
.
```

expected output

```
more file.conf

hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=100
hadoop.tasklog.purgeLogSplits=true
hadoop.tasklog.logsRetainHours=12
.
.
```

Comment: Why do you make config file changes using scripts to start with?

Comment: we are working on log4j configuration , and some old conf comes with old values

Comment: when asking question, please also add what you have tried yourself to solve this.. this is not a free coding service site.. you have asked and received lots of answers on text processing questions, by now you should be able to at least make an attempt to solve it..

Comment: @yael - you're clearly working on Hadoop, is this vanilla apache, Hortonworks or Cloudera? There are better methods to manage these than editing the files with `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F= '/hadoop\.tasklog\.totalLogFileSize/ && $2 != 100 { next } 1' file
hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=100
hadoop.tasklog.purgeLogSplits=true
hadoop.tasklog.logsRetainHours=12
```

This treats the file as `=`-delimited fields.  If a line matches the given pattern, and if the number after `=` (i.e. the second field) is not 100, then the line is skipped and not outputted.  All other lines are outputted by the trailing `1` at the end of the program (which could be replaced by `{ print }`).

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed '/hadoop\.tasklog\.totalLogFileSize/{ /=100$/!d; }' file
hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=100
hadoop.tasklog.purgeLogSplits=true
hadoop.tasklog.logsRetainHours=12
```

This outputs all lines, but when a line matches the given pattern, and then does *not* match `=100` at the end of the line, it is deleted from the input.

Comment: this is very great idea to do it with awk , but actually I tag sed and perl one liner since we want the option "sed -i" or "perl -i" to edit the file , with awk we need to copy the file that created to the source file , and we want to avoid that   ( +1 for your effort )

Comment: @yael See updated answer.